# Shell Script — Get all files modified after <date>

Tags: unix, shell

I'd rather not do this in PHP so I'm hoping a someone decent at shell scripting can help.

I need a script that runs through directory recursively and finds all files with last modified date is greater than some date.  Then, it will tar and zip the file(s) keeping the path information.

Comment: Good decision to not do it in PHP.

Comment: You could use any of the decent shell scripting languages, eg python, ruby, perl without resorting to php.

Comment: @garrow This would actually be fairly simple in PHP using a RecursiveDirctoryIterator encaspulated in a FilterIterator.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

as simple as:

```
find . -mtime -1 | xargs tar --no-recursion -czf myfile.tgz
```

where `find . -mtime -1` will select all the files in (recursively) current directory modified day before. you can use fractions, for example:

```
find . -mtime -1.5 | xargs tar --no-recursion -czf myfile.tgz
```

Comment: See user104848's answer below for how to deal with spaces in your file names

Comment: Converting an arbitrary timestamp into a fractional, relative amount of time seems neither correct nor particularly convenient. The solution below using `-newermt` is *much* nicer.

Comment: When trying to extract any files with changes in a structure with directories, the directories themselves are marked modified causing the entire folder to be archived. Add `-type f` to only select files. This maintains the folder structure, but only backs up files with changes.

Comment: @BrianHenk user104848 changed their name, I'm pretty sure you mean [this answer from (currently) Jason Luther](http://stackoverflow.com/a/848609/327074) though

Comment: The question asks to find files by an arbitrary date. This answer is how to find files by an arbitrary number of days in the past.  I don't think this should be the accepted answer without adding a step to convert a date into a day delta.

Comment: For how to use a plain text date, see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date#comment11129026_848327)

Comment: big caveat: if xargs have to append "too many" files, it will invoke "tar ... -c..." multiple times, and thus will overwrite the previous invocations and you end up with only the last invocation's files in myfile.tgz.

Answer (score 97):

If you have GNU `find`, then there are a legion of relevant options.  The only snag is that the interface to them is less than stellar:

- `-mmin n` (modification time in minutes)
- `-mtime n` (modification time in days)
- `-newer file` (modification time newer than modification time of file)
- `-daystart` (adjust start time from current time to start of day)
- Plus alternatives for access time and 'change' or 'create' time.

The hard part is determining the number of minutes since a time.

One option worth considering: use `touch` to create a file with the required modification time stamp; then use `find` with `-newer`.

```
touch -t 200901031231.43 /tmp/wotsit
find . -newer /tmp/wotsit -print
rm -f /tmp/wotsit
```

This looks for files newer than 2009-01-03T12:31:43.  Clearly, in a script, `/tmp/wotsit` would be a name with the PID or other value to make it unique; and there'd be a `trap` to ensure it gets removed even if the user interrupts, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Instead, you can use `-newermt '2009-01-03T12:31:43'` to avoid the need to create a file just for reference.

Comment: @MichaelMior: Interesting - the 'find' on MacOS X 10.7.2 supports `-newermt` (documented under `-newerXY` since there are multiple options; X = m, Y = t in this case).  The GNU find on the (almost archaic) Linux systems I use does not support the options, so it is a relatively recent arrival.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This option is present in GNU find 4.4.2 which I'm using on my system.

Comment: It's not present in GNU find 4.2.27 which I'm using on one of my systems.  So, that gives a window of GNU versions.  MacOS X `find` does not support the `--version` option (or `-V`).

Comment: Great solution, but -newermt is much, MUCH nicer! :-)

Comment: Also note that GNU find supports relative times as well, ie. `-newermt '-2 weeks'`.

Comment: `-newermt '2009-01-03T12:31:43'` looks awesome, but sadly it seems to interpret everything in the wrong timezone: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2012-12/msg00009.html

Comment: @antoine: Curious, but there does seem to be a problem with time zones as reported.  It is also curious that it hasn't been fixed in the 5+ years since it was reported.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In case anyone is stuck with that timezone issue, using the date format `Tue Jan 30 14:22:35 2018` instead of `2018-01-30T14:22:35` seems to solve the issue for me. No clue why though.

Comment: I guess `-newermt` is so relevant that it is worth editing the answer.

Answer (score 38):

You can do this directly with tar and even better:

```
tar -N '2014-02-01 18:00:00' -jcvf archive.tar.bz2 files
```

This instructs tar to compress files newer than 1st of January 2014, 18:00:00.

Comment: Huh... I've been using Unix since 1984 and never knew this. Always something to learn.

Comment: The implementations of `tar` that come with OS X and FreeBSD only support `--newer` which is the long option for `-N` in GNU `tar`.

Comment: This is awesome... I could only get it to work with bzip, not using -xcvf and a gz extension... but I'm no expert.

Answer (score 17):

This will work for some number of files. You want to include "-print0" and "xargs -0" in case any of the paths have spaces in them. This example looks for files modified in the last 7 days. To find those modified before the last 7 days, use "+7".

```
find . -mtime -7 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cjf /foo/archive.tar.bz2
```

As [this page](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm) warns, xargs can cause the tar command to be executed multiple times if there are a lot of arguments, and the "-c" flag could cause problems. In that case, you would want this:

```
find . -mtime -7 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rf /foo/archive.tar
```

You can't update a zipped tar archive with tar, so you would have to bzip2 or gzip it in a second step.

Comment: Regarding the second point, you can use a gzip-enabled tar command, like Gnu tar's -z option, to update zipped archives, too.

Comment: Or add the 'j' option to use bzip in recent GNU tars

Comment: As I said above on Jonathan's answer, this will grab the folders which have changes causing all of their files to be imported. Add `-type f` to only select files. This maintains the folder structure, but only backs up the files with changes/added recently.

Answer (score 12):

This should show all files modified within the last 7 days.

```
find . -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

Pipe that into tar/zip, and you should be good.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply do the following to backup all new files from 7 days ago

```
tar --newer $(date -d'7 days ago' +"%d-%b") -zcf thisweek.tgz .
```

note you can also replace '7 days ago' with anything that suits your need

Can be : `date -d'yesterday' +"%d-%b"`

Or even : `date -d'first Sunday last month' +"%d-%b"`

Answer (score 3):

well  under linux try reading man page of the find command

```
man find
```

something like this should

```
 find . -type f -mtime -7 -print -exec cat {} \; | tar cf - | gzip -9
```

and you have it

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of files last modified later than x days ago with:

```
find . -mtime -x
```

Then you just have to tar and zip files in the resulting list, e.g.:

```
tar czvf mytarfile.tgz `find . -mtime -30`
```

for all files modified during last month.

Comment: "-mtime x" matches files modified exactly "x" days ago, use "-mtime -x" to match files modified less than "x" days ago.

Answer (score 2):

This script will find files having a modification date of two minutes before and after the given date (and you can change the values in the conditions as per your requirement)

```
PATH_SRC="/home/celvas/Documents/Imp_Task/"
PATH_DST="/home/celvas/Downloads/zeeshan/"

cd $PATH_SRC
TODAY=$(date  -d "$(date +%F)" +%s)
TODAY_TIME=$(date -d "$(date +%T)" +%s)


for f in `ls`;
do
#       echo "File -> $f"
        MOD_DATE=$(stat -c %y "$f")
        MOD_DATE=${MOD_DATE% *}
#       echo MOD_DATE: $MOD_DATE
        MOD_DATE1=$(date -d "$MOD_DATE" +%s)
#       echo MOD_DATE: $MOD_DATE

DIFF_IN_DATE=$[ $MOD_DATE1 - $TODAY ]
DIFF_IN_DATE1=$[ $MOD_DATE1 - $TODAY_TIME ]
#echo DIFF: $DIFF_IN_DATE
#echo DIFF1: $DIFF_IN_DATE1
if [[ ($DIFF_IN_DATE -ge -120) && ($DIFF_IN_DATE1 -le 120) && (DIFF_IN_DATE1 -ge -120) ]]
then
echo File lies in Next Hour = $f
echo MOD_DATE: $MOD_DATE

#mv $PATH_SRC/$f  $PATH_DST/$f
fi
done
```

For example you want files having modification date before the given date only, you may change `120` to `0` in `$DIFF_IN_DATE` parameter discarding the conditions of `$DIFF_IN_DATE1` parameter.

Similarly if you want files having modification date 1 hour before and after given date,
just replace `120` by `3600` in `if CONDITION`.