# Linux - find files after and before a particular file

Tags: linux

Im trying to find files on my computer that has been created 1 hour before and 1 hour after a particular file has been created.

This is the method i tried -

```
find /root -newermt "2012-10-04 1800" -and -newermt "2012-10-04 2000" -exec ls -ldb {} \;
```

the directory on my linux is root, the particular file created was created at 19:00

this is another method i tried which work but it only displayed one result of after or before not both! >

```
find /root/Downloads -type f \( -newer /root/Downloads/alex.txt ! -newer /root/Downloads/hesham.txt \)
```

Comment: Seems -not is missing in first solution -and in second

Comment: isnt ! the same as -not? or am i confused

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
# missing a -not here ---------------------v
find /root -newermt "2012-10-04 1800" -and -not -newermt "2012-10-04 2000" -exec ls -ldb {} \;
```

This does:

1. all files in `/root`
2. that are newer than **"2012-10-04 1800"**
3. and that are *not* newer than **"2012-10-04 2000"** (or older than **"2012-10-04 2000"**)

Comment: is there a way that i can pass the file name directly within the `newer` quotation so that i can get the files which have been created after that file which i have given it within the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient solution but ..

touch /tmp/temp -t time-of-file-creation-1hr

touch /tmp/ntemp -t time-of-file-creation+1hr

find . -newer /tmp/temp -a ! -newer /tmp/ntemp -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null