# How to grep a group of files within a specific time range

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to write a script used on a buffer box that does full packet capture of network traffic. As it's for a fairly big network we split the captures into 100MB segments. At times of high network traffic oftentimes over a one minute period we will have multiple pcaps which cover that period.

So what I want to do is have a bash script that lets the analyst who is searching for something specify a date and time and how many minutes either side of it they want to search for files. Obviously I can do something like this -

```
ls -al | grep "Dec  1" | grep 02:00
ls -al | grep "Dec  1" | grep 02:01
```

and so on, get each result and grep each file individually for the specific keyword I'm looking for, but I'd like to be able to do a wider search for all files created within a time range and then grep each of them for the keyword.

I'm not entirely sure how to do that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want files in a time range or want log in time range in the files ?

Comment: `find` is your friend, with the `-ctime`, `-newer` and/or `-mtime` options (among others).  This, piped into `xargs` is a favorite idiom to grab a bunch of files based on some criteria, then do things to them.

Comment: What I want is for an analyst to say 1st December at 11:00am with a keyword of "foo" searching 5 minutes either side. The script should find all files created between 10:55am and 11:05am and grep them for the keyword "foo"

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735182/linux-find-files-after-and-before-a-particular-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2013-10-28 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2013-10-29 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is for an analyst to say 1st December at 11:00am with a
>   keyword of "foo" searching 5 minutes either side. The script should
>   find all files created between 10:55am and 11:05am and grep them for
>   the keyword "foo"

This script uses `touch -d` to create temporary files with time stamps of the start and end of the time range, because older versions of `find` have the option `-newer` only, not `-newermt`, and `touch -d` conveniently allows using the given time specification (with little modification) with the minutes adjustment. The necessary modifications to the given date are done with `sed` and consist of moving the day after the month and removing suffixes as *st* or *nd* as well as the word *at*.

```
read -p'date and time: ' dat
read -p'+/- minutes: ' min
read -p'keyword: ' key
dat=`sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)\(st\|nd\|rd\|th\|\) \([^ ]*\)/\3 \1/; s/at //' <<<$dat`
touch -d"$dat $min min" /tmp/to
touch -d"$dat -$min min" /tmp/from
find . -type f -newer /tmp/from ! -newer /tmp/to | xargs grep "$key"
rm /tmp/from /tmp/to
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `find` with the `-cmin` or `-ctime` arguments.

So,

```
find -iname "*.log" -mtime +30 -mtime -90 -exec grep plasma {} \;
```

, would find files ending in ".log" which were modified greater than 30 days ago, but less than 90 days, then run said file through `grep` looking for the word "plasma".

Comment: If you're not going to provide a more complete answer, then this should be a comment.

Comment: I've looked into this, but I don't want to look X minutes back, I need to look for files of a specific date and between 2 times. See my comment above.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2013-10-28 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2013-10-29 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Say you want 20131130 from 0100 to 0130  - 
This does that with find:

```
touch -t 201311300100 dummy1
touch -t 201311300130 dummy2 
find /path/to/logs type -f \( -newer dummy1 -a ! -newer dummy2 \) -name '*.log'
```

the 201311300100 bit is a touch timestring.  I posted the most vanilla version I know because of the UNIX tag....