# view all files edited on a particular day

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vi

I want to know if there is a way in linux to view a list of files I have edited on a particular day.  I know if I do ls -lt it will list folders and files by last modified but I want to see a list of files in subfolders etc and ls -lt only works for the current folder I am in (not files in subfolders).I know on windows explorer for example you can search for file by date modified so I presume there would be something similar in linux but can't see how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example, This may help you.

```
ls -lRc | grep "Nov 28"
```

**Small description**

```
-l Shows you huge amounts of information (permissions, owners, size, and when last modified.
-R  Includes the contents of subdirectories.
-c  Use time of last modification of the i-node (file created, mode changed, and so forth) for sorting (-t) or printing (-l or -n).
```

Answer (score 1):

This will go even into sub directory:

```
ls -lRt
```

For excluding any particular directory, use this:

```
ls | tee | grep -Fxv "folder_name" | xargs ls -lRt
```

Comment: this is what I am after thanks.  can you add something on the end to exclude a particular folder from this list?

Answer (score 0):

You should able to use find with -mtime.

find |path to directory| -mtime -1 -print

Actually [Shell Script — Get all files modified after <date>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date)  has all the answers.