# How to zip latest created file in unix

Tags: unix, zip

I want to zip number of files created on particular day. I used this command

```
zip -rt 06222012 TEST root/*.csv
```

this command zipped all the files in root directory with .csv extension created on date >=22/6/2012

But this doesn't meet my requirement. My requirement is..
lets suppose there are two scripts a.sh and b.sh
a.sh(Manual run) executes at time 22/6/2012 1:00 AM and completes at 22/6/2012 4:00 AM and creates 4 .csv file

After this b.sh file executes through cron job on 22/6/2012 6:00 AM and completes at 22/6/2012 10:00 AM and creates 5 .csv file

Above zip command will zip all these 9 files as they are created on same day that is 22/6/2012, but I need only 5 .csv files which get created by b.sh only, that means the files which got created on 22/6/2012 10:00 AM

In the above zip command can I also give the hour and minute too ?

Comment: What about having a more explicit name for `*.csv` depending on the script creating them? If you do `*4.csv` for `a.sh`, then you can `zip -rt 06222012 TEST root/*4.csv`.

Comment: Note that the `-t` option deals with the **modification** time, not the **creation** time. In POSIX, creation time of files is not recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact already mentioned in the comments above that with using a standard filesystem your only chance is to approximate "files created" by "files last modified" you probably might want to adress the problem using `find`.

There already is a good article about that on stackoverflow (see: [Shell Script — Get all files modified after <date>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date))

Regarding your case most probably the `-newerXY` option might be the one best fitting to the problem with something like:

```
  zip -r TEST `find root -name"*.csv" -newermt 10:00`
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Actually the files are created by a sql procedure which is called by two scripts a.sh and b.sh, one rum manually and another one through cron job. Name of files contain year, month and some particular name. These things are generated dynamically in sql procedure. I missed one test case above. I think through this code I won't be able to zip right files, because lets suppose manual script(a.sh) creates 4 files in time duration 26/4/2012 4 am to 26/4/2012 10 am, 1 file at 4:30, another at 6, another at 8 and last one at 10

Comment: Now when cron job(b.sh) is executed at time 26/4/2012 6 am to 26/4/2012 2 PM, 1 file get created at  6:30 am, another at 9 am and so on. So if you see in case I Zip through this code, I will eventually zip some of the files created through a.sh, which I don't need.

I see only this option now, that when sql procedure is running and creating files, at that time I write those names in some temp file and then through unix, I read that file and zip only those particular files.

If you see any other option that without changing .sql file, this can be achieved by unix script too, please let me know

Comment: If I understood your problem right it are only the files generated by running b.sh you're interested in. If this is the case instead of trying to figure out which files got created by b.sh later on maybe it might be a better idea to directly zip them once they are created in b.sh. If directly zipped from the b.sh script there's no need to by some arcane magic try to figure out which script created a file as the information is directly present. As an alternative you might try to tag the files with a different name - e.g. `xxx.a.csv`` and `xxx.b.csv` if this doesn't break anything.

Comment: yes, thats what I did, but instead of doing it in b.sh , I had to do it in .sql file which generates those files. Fron .sql I temporarily stored those names of required files in one particular temporary file. Then from b.sh, I read that temp file and zipped the respective files. It worked :)