# How to select "equal to/newer than" files based on time input in Solaris/Shell

Tags: bash, unix, awk, solaris, ksh

Following is a basic output of `ls -ltrh` (in Solaris):

```
-rw--r--r-- 57 oracle  dba   1.9K Jan 18 14:38 file001.log
-rw--r--r-- 30 oracle  dba   1.0K Jan 18 14:41 file002.log
-rw--r--r--  8 oracle  dba   272B Jan 18 15:33 file003.log
-rw--r--r--  8 oracle  dba   272B Jan 18 15:35 file004.log
```

The application output for time is always in the following format (can not be changed), based on which I need to select the files >= date:

```
01/18/2016 14:41
```

In the above case, I need all files from Jan 18, with timestamp of 14:41 and newer.

Comment: [Please also post your attempt to solve this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question should include your own code, your expect results, along with your actual results or any errors that were produced when you tried to run your code.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is [not considered](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

After cutting/ sed / whatever, transform the date `01/18/2016 14:41` into `201601181441.00`. Now create a tmp file with that timestamp and look for newer files:

```
touch -t 201601181441.00 /tmp/olddate
find . -newer /tmp/olddate -print
rm -f /tmp/olddate
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different approach here- instead of using `ls` and parsing the output, you can use unix [find](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html) command.

for example, this will give you files modified in the past week:

```
find . -mtime -7
```

you can also use `-newer` flag to get all files newer than some specific file (and then use the trick shown on the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848293/shell-script-get-all-files-modified-after-date) to get newer than specific date)

Comment: Thanks Nir. However, my challenge remains of converting the search based on the date/time output shown above. Also, this is Solaris.